# Visual artifacts with the title bar of a JFrame

Tags: java, windows, swing, jframe, scaling

I'm working with an application based on java swing and I faced some visual artifacts with the title bar of a basic JFrame if I use the display scaling option from Windows 10. I let the system controls the "Window System decorated" including the title bar Look & Feel because I don't want to customize this part.

For example, if I set 150% I have 2 issues:

- issue1: garbage line
- issue2: minimize, maximize and close buttons are blinking on mouse hover

My Setup/config:

```
Java Swing
Windows 10
Adopt open JDK 11
Enable "Override high DPI" option with System Enhanced
```

What I tried:

- I used a basic JFrame demo from the Oracle website, but the same issues
- No scaling i.e 100% the display is OK, no more problem.
- Uncheck the "Override high DPI" option and scaling of 150%, the display is OK, no more problem

It seems that there is something wrong with "Override high DPI/System Enhanced" and scaling...

[image: screenshots]

Basic JFrame example from Oracle can be used to see both artifacts:

```java
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("FrameDemo");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
 
    JLabel emptyLabel = new JLabel("");
    emptyLabel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(175, 100));
    frame.getContentPane().add(emptyLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
 
    //Display the window.
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Please post your code to reproduce the issue, and a question: why do you need to set "Override high DPI" on?

Comment: My own application has been written without taking the DPI of displays into account and not able to natively render their contents on High-DPI displays. The scaling helps to increase the size of visual elements (e.g. text, images, icons) but some of them are blurry. With "Override High-DPI" "System or System Enhanced) option, the visual elements appear much sharper especially for the text and a kind of anti-aliasing is applied on images and icons.

Comment: This sounds strange to me, since I noticed that when windows scaling is set >100% I automatically get a proper graphics object (with a proper transform set) in painting, so everything is automatically scaled to the right size. Can you post (if not too problematic) a small example?

Comment: I understand that images can be blurry since they are simply upscaled, but cannot understand why text (and in general standard swing elements) should not be rendered properly.